# Cascading DR - Switchover issue in Oracle

Tags: oracle, replication, recovery, disaster-recovery, dataguard

I have 3 databases:`A`, `B`, `C`.

`A` is the primary database, and the `log_arhive_dest_2` parameter is set accordingly:

`log_arhive_dest_2=service='A' ASYNC valid_for=online_logfile,PRIMARY_ROLE`

`B` is the standby of `A` with parameter:

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------

log_archive_dest_5                   string      SERVICE=B ASYNC VALID_FO
                                                 R=(STANDBY_LOGFILES,STANDBY_RO
                                                 LE) DB_UNIQUE_NAME=B
```

`C` is the standby of `B` with no `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST` parameter set:

When a switchover is performed, and `B` is now the primary, the problem is, because of **Cascading DR** as I know, When B is sending the archives to standby DB's, The **Cascading Standby** "C" is not receiving the archives.

The only workaround I found was changing B database's `log_archive_dest_2` parameter to:

`log_arhive_dest_2=service='B' ASYNC valid_for=online_logfile,PRIMARY_ROLE`

Can someone help me find a workaround where I don't have to alter the `log_archive_dest_2` parameter and set `B` primary in `log_archive_dest_2`?

//Edit:

I have updated the values for `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST` for all databases